# How to include boost when building using eosio.cdt?

Tags: eosio.cdt, cmake, boost

I'd like to use the multiprecision library, but i'm having problems including the header filer.

CMakeLists:

```
include(ExternalProject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# if no cdt root is given use default path
if(EOSIO_CDT_ROOT STREQUAL "" OR NOT EOSIO_CDT_ROOT)
   find_package(eosio.cdt)
endif()

ExternalProject_Add(
   chintaidex_project
   SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src
   BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/chintaidex
   CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${EOSIO_CDT_ROOT}/lib/cmake/eosio.cdt/EosioWasmToolchain.cmake -I=$(BOOST_DIR)/include/
   UPDATE_COMMAND ""
   PATCH_COMMAND ""
   TEST_COMMAND ""
   INSTALL_COMMAND ""
   BUILD_ALWAYS 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CMakeLists file in the base folder should not be changed. But rather in the src folder CMakeList you should add the following line:

```
target_include_directories( mycontract PUBLIC "$ENV{BOOST_DIR}/include" )
```

Where BOOST_DIR is an environmental variable pointing to your boost folder. On my computer it is:
`/home/eosio/1.8/src/boost_1_70_0`